# Forgot password flow does not work, getting email with a link but after clicking link it's not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, password

Forgot password does not work, getting an email with a link but after clicking the link it's asking to fill email in again instead of being able to fill in a new password.

I am using the WooCommerce page for resetting my password. And after filling in the email, it does send the email which I receive correctly. Although after clicking the reset link it shows me the same form again, which is asking to fill in my email/username and it should be showing a field to pick a new password. It does append the /?show-reset-form=true to the URL

[WooCommerce lost password reset flow not working with SendGrid (redirect loop)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312100/woocommerce-lost-password-reset-flow-not-working-with-sendgrid-redirect-loop)

I did found above thread, I got the same problem and I use Mailgun for my mail. I tried turning of link tracking but the issue still persists while the links are back to normal again and it also gives the KEY and ID like it should.

Comment: The fact that you're getting the ?show-reset-form=true makes me think this isn't the root problem, but does the link in the email match the formatting I mention in #3 [here](https://www.mail-mechanic.com/password-reset-fixes#email-reset-looping)? If the link seems ok, can you check (with your browser's developer tools panel) that a cookie starting with wp-resetpass is being set in your browser? If it's not, I suspect caching or security plugins are preventing it from being sent, or browser settings are blocking it.

Comment: @DanWich Thank you for your reply! I have tested it and the cookie is not being set, although I have also tried disabling all plugins and themes including my caching and it still didnt work. I am also using incognito so I doubt that my browser is blocking it

Comment: Is it possible your host is doing some caching that's ignoring non-whitelisted cookies? I think WP Engine is one example that needs an exemption for cookies starting with wp-resetpass. You can sometimes see headers in the developer tools that show whether there was a cache "miss" or "hit", where you only want to be seeing "miss" during the reset.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue a few days ago. I figured out that the problem was in my theme. How did I knew that. I disabled all the plugins and tried again but the problem still there so I connected my hosting to help me and they just whitelisted my IP-addresse in Security Mode but the problem still there so I switched to the Twenty Fifteen theme and it's worked. So the problem was in my theme. I connected the theme author and they said they will release an update to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried applying WP default theme AND disabling all the plugins but the problem still persists.